# How to make an activity start after receiving result from a server?

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I am working on an Android app which requires some data from Facebook. I have a tabbed activity which use fragments to display the tabs. In one of those tabs, I want to display the result from request made to Facebook.

Currently, the activity shows up before the response is received and therefore doesn't show the expected result.

Is there a way to start the activity after the response is received or maybe update the fragment to display the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask` for this.

Put your request on `doInBackground()` and after it finishes, it goes to `onPostExecute()`. That's where you can update your layout/start another activity.

You can read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html